# SharePoint 2010: Set a fixed upload location

Tags: 2010, development, custom-form

When using Announcements or Discussion forms it's possible to upload a document when entering data into the body field. (The editing tools are available and when clicking on the insert tab the Upload file option appears)

Is it possible to adjust the upload form to use a defined fixed upload location.
E.g. The dropdown list is "Upload To" only shows "Shared Documents"
And this only for certain content types? (E.g. Announcements list, Discussion list, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the dropdown, lists all the document libraries in a site that you have access to.

You will have to change the "RteUploadDialog.aspx" in the Layouts folder in the 14 hive to accomplish this. Search for the Dropdown "TargetList" and add a line similar to the code below to get the document library you wish to get selected. Here I have made "Documents" Library as my default selected value.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="TargetList" onchange="CheckUniquePermissions(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" Width="320px" runat="server" DataTextField="Documents">
<asp:ListItem Selected ="True" Text="Documents" Value="2fd2a13d-3c11-4bf0-8638-6ddfd45c35cb"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The ID of the library can be retrieved by getting the view source of the popup page. Everything should work fine, but I would not recommend editing the core files inside the layouts folder which could breach your warranty with Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks Deepu, Is there no option to put this in a feature/solution and overwrite the default "Upload File" behavior? (Hide the original upload button and replace it with a custom one with code behind that starts from a copy of the RteUploadDialog.aspx")

Comment: Create this as a separate page in layouts folder and check out the option to use SPWebApplication.UpdateMappedPage - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.updatemappedpage.aspx   or try writing an httpmodule which could intercept user requests and redirect to the custom aspx page.

Comment: Is it possible to do this only for one specific site collection?

Comment: SPWebApplication.UpdateMappedPage is implemented for a single web application. Your custom code in an httpmodule can be logically formulated to check only the specific site collection that you desire.